# Two dropdowns list interacting each other

Tags: drop-down-menu

I have a drop down list(Multi select with check boxes) with list of Countries.As soon as I check an item in the first drop down, I should list all the unchecked items in the second drop down.And viceversa. Can anyone help me out ?.

I have used bootstrap multi select drop down list.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I Suggest you to use a list of objects with Value and Text properties Like    Below

```
var data=[{Value:1,Text:"India"},{Value:2,Text:"USA"},.......]
```

and in the document.ready() function write the code

```
for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
  $("#ddlCountry").append(new Option(data[i].Value, data[i].Text));
```

Then use the

```
  $("#ddlCountry").change()
```

event to delete the selected element from the list and add the new data list to the second drop down list..